# Iptables error while adding a redirect

Tags: centos, iptables

I am trying to apply the following:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --src 0/0 --dst [MY IP] -p tcp --dport 40 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
```

However I get the following error:

```
iptables v1.3.5: can't initialize iptables table `/sbin/nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I am running CentOS 5.5. Can anyone please advise?

**UPDATE**

`ifconfig` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:51:A4:3E:E0
          inet addr:x.x.x.x  Bcast:173.201.16.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::218:51ff:fea4:3ee0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29678326 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13545931 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2604591444 (2.4 GiB)  TX bytes:6052013635 (5.6 GiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:34139502 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34139502 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:5160432652 (4.8 GiB)  TX bytes:5160432652 (4.8 GiB)

lo:1      Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:97.74.207.156  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1

lo:2      Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:173.201.181.56  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
```

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux ip-173-201-16-45.ip.secureserver.net 2.6.18-028stab070.14 #1 SMP Thu Nov 18 16:04:02 MSK 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

**UPDATE 2**

`grep -v \# /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config` output:

```
IPTABLES_MODULES=""

IPTABLES_MODULES_UNLOAD="yes"

IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_STOP="no"

IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_RESTART="no"

IPTABLES_SAVE_COUNTER="no"

IPTABLES_STATUS_NUMERIC="yes"

IPTABLES_STATUS_VERBOSE="no"
```

**UPDATE 3**

`sudo /sbin/iptables -L` output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

`sudo /sbin/lsmod | egrep -i iptables` output: BLANK.

`sudo /sbin/lsmod | egrep -i nat` output: BLANK.

**UPDATE 4**

`uname -a` outputs:

```
Linux ip-173-201-16-45.ip.secureserver.net 2.6.18-028stab070.14 #1 SMP Thu Nov 18 16:04:02 MSK 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please give us the output of `ifconfig`, `lspci`, and `uname -a`?

Comment: @quanta - Hi. I have added `ifconfig` and `uname - a` output above, but `lspci` returns an error `bash: lspci: command not found`. I have tried using `sudo lspci` and `/sbin/lspci` but no luck.

Comment: Assuming the system is fully up to date, and the firewall config is free of syntax errors... what is the output of sudo /sbin/iptables -L sudo /sbin/lsmod | egrep -i iptables sudo /sbin/lsmod | egrep -i nat

Comment: what is output for # "lsmod |grep nat" AND "grep -v \# /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config". do you start /etc/init.d/iptables ?

Comment: Try updating kernel unless haven't already.

Comment: @Rikih - Hi, `lsmod |grep nat` outputs a blank. `grep -v \# /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config` is pasted above under UPDATE 2. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I have added the output under UPDATE 3 above. The last two commands outputted blank. Thank you.

Comment: @poige - What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: just start /etc/init.d/iptables start ?, and lsmod|grep nat again. or modprobe iptable_nat and try again ?

Comment: @Rikih - I started it again OK. `lsmod |grep nat` still blank. `modprobe iptable_nat` outputted `FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.18-028stab070.14/modules.dep: No such file or directory`. Is this my problem?

Comment: Check if 1. you're running a virtual machine with [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/). 2. iptables is compiled in your kernel with: `grep CONFIG_IP_NF /path/to/your/kernel/.config` and 3. `rpm -qa | grep kernel-xen`?

Comment: seems yes, your kernel could be not compiled with iptable_nat module. # cat /lib/modules/`uname -r`/modules.dep|grep iptable_  <- you should be found iptable modules (one of them should be iptable_nat.ko). or try to locate iptable_nat.ko on /lib/modules/`uname -r`/

Comment: @quanta - 1. virt-what outputs 'openvz'. I am working on 2 and 3 now..

Comment: @quanta - 2. How do I find the path to my kernel? and 3. outputs blank.

Comment: Also post the content of `/etc/modprobe.conf`?

Comment: By the default: `/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)-$(uname -m)/.config`

Comment: @quanta - `/etc/modprobe.conf` cannot be found. I have tried searching for `modprobe.conf` but no luck. `/usr/src/kernels/` is empty. I have tried listing the contents with `ls` and `ls -a` but there is nothing inside.

Comment: @Christopher: please do this command **cat /proc/modules** and post reply. I have a feeling you are using a monolithic kernel. Would also help a **uname -a** and a **find /lib/modules -name 'ipta*'**

Comment: @tagram - Hi. `cat /proc/modules` outputs a blank. `uname -a` is ouputted above under UPDATE 4 and ` find /lib/modules -name 'ipta*'` also shows up blank. Thanks.

Comment: `grep conntrack /etc/modules.conf`?

Comment: @Christopher let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1097/discussion-between-quanta-and-christopher)

Comment: cat /boot/config-`uname -r`|grep "IPTABL\|NAT" ?, if you cannot found CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT, re-compile your kernel.

Comment: use yum to update your system. `man yum` or google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your kernel version you are running inside an OpenVZ container.

Either you are missing the NAT libraries in /lib/xtables and/or the OpenVZ kernel does not actually have the NAT kernel module loaded - I would wager that the latter is most likely the case; if you want NAT you will need to ask your VPS provider to load the module for you.

Comment: Hi. Yeah, looks like the only option now. I have now raised a ticket with Godaddy. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, my VPS provider does not support NAT modules and cannot change my kernel. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config as follows:

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="iptable_nat"
```

Comment: Hi. I have added that to the config and restarted iptables but the error still apppears..

Comment: You should then preload the module: insmod iptable_nat